# Evitar que se pierdan datos de un activity al abrir otro

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un activity donde tienen imagenes y texto.
el problema es que al abrir el siguiente se pierde la información.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Numeros_App.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Como puedo mantener la información de imagenes y texto que se encuentra.

```
i.putExtra
```

supongo no es una opcion para esto.

Necesito regresar a este activity que contiene esa información sin que se pierdan los datos.

Comment: Podrías ser mas especifico? Con 'Evitar que se pierda' te refieres a mantener la información en la misma activity o deseas pasar esa información a la nueva activity?

Comment: ¿Que tipo (o que cantidad) de información tratas de mantener?

Comment: Mantener la información en el activity, es decir, al volverlo abrir.

Comment: Siendo ese el caso necesitas guardar el estado de la activity, en este momento tengo un ejemplo a la mano de como lo puedes hacer, pero te dejo este enlace que tal vez te pueda ayudar; https://sekthdroid.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/mantener-los-datos-cuando-rotemos-la-pantalla-en-android/

Comment: Una actividad no se cierra si tu no se lo indica. Si al abrir la otra actividad, si no haces un finish no se elimina y al volver atrás sigue estando como estaba, no hay que hacer nada

Answer (score 0):

Digamos que quieres pasar el contenido de un string con un putExtra desde una actividad a la otra, por ejemplo, yo tengo un intent que va de una clase a otra, y cuando llevo a la clase UserEdit un putExtra con el tag "Nombre" y despues de la coma el contenido que debe llevar Nombre, que es de tipo string

```
adapter.getItem(position).getNombre()
```

esta linea me retorna un String con un nombre y lo almacena con el Tag "Nombre"

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserEdit.class);                    
                          intent.putExtra("Nombre",adapter.getItem(position).getNombre());
```

Ahora, para obtener este valor en mi otra actividad

```
 Intent iin= getIntent();
         Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

        if(b!=null)
        {
            String n =(String) b.get("Nombre");
            Log.e("El nombre es: ",""+n);
}else{
Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo traer el Extra", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Solo creo un getIntent, y un Bundle el cual obtiene los extras , chequeo que sea distinto de null para confirmar que viene con algun contenido, y luego pongo b.get("Nombre") y obtengo el Nombre desde mi otra activity

Asi funciona para obtener datos de una activity a otra